# How to use expect script in local machine

Tags: expect

I understand we have to spawn a process to interact with it using expect and send.

I had been spawing ssh and running several commands in the remote machine using send, expect, send, expect.

Now i am not pretty sure now.how i can run the similar command using expect in local machine.

Could be please help me to understand this concern

Comment: to make it simple, whether can i use expect script to run automation on local machine ? if so what is the spawn command to start the process

Comment: For example i wanna run a sql script using expect script on same local machine then i execute the following code it works fine. but i do not need to take remote and do the operation.                                                        `code`    spawn ssh root@172.16.1.184        exp_send -s -- "psql -d scdb -U scdbuser -p 12740 < $del_sql_script \r"   expect "Password for user dbuser: "   exp_send -s -- "db_passw0rd\r" `code`

Comment: If you have a specific script, edit it into the question. Your comment is not readable at all. Also, I'm not an expect expert (I came from the bash tag, which I have since removed), so I'm done with this question.

Comment: As I said, edit the scripts into your question. Please stop posting code in comments.

Comment: sorry for the interrupt . I will first understand the basics since i am new to expect script.